# Пытаюсь написать функцию которая будет конвертировать строку в массив, аналог string.split в джс, только на С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

По идее в функцию будет передаваться строка, там итерироваться и возвращать массив(вектор)
Если передать в неё: `"Привет, меня зовут Name: я увлекаюсь программированием."` 
То на выходе должно быть:

```
vector<string> strArr = {"Привет", ",", "меня", "зовут","Name", ":",
"я", "увлекаюсь ", "программированием", "."};
```

```
#include "baseIncludeConfig.h"

vector<string> s_to_arr(string str)
{
    string resStr;
    vector<string> resArr;


    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ':' || str[i] == ',' || str[i] == '.')
        {
            resArr.push_back(string(1, str[i]));
        }
        if (str[i] != ' ' && i < str.length())
        {
            resStr += string(1, str[i]);
            continue;
        }
        resArr.push_back(resStr);
        resStr = "";
    }


    return resArr;
}
#include "baseIncludeConfig.h"

vector<string> s_to_arr(string str)
{
    string resStr;
    vector<string> resArr;


    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ':' || str[i] == ',' || str[i] == '.')
        {
            resArr.push_back(string(1, str[i]));
        }
        if (str[i] != ' ' && i < str.length())
        {
            resStr += string(1, str[i]);
            continue;
        }
        resArr.push_back(resStr);
        resStr = "";
    }


    return resArr;
}
```

Этот код работает, но есть баг: запятые, точки и пробелы, и остальные символы пушатся перед словами.

Comment: Наверное у вас ошибка в примере правильного ответа, в элементе `"увлекаюсь "` вы оставили пробел, а в других его нет. Опишите подробнее, чем именно разделитель пробел отличается от прочих.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, подойдет [std::regex_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator).